# Modal window from within Wordpress admin

Tags: admin, wp-admin

How can get a modal window to work from within the wordpress admin?

I want to create a modal window that will work from a meta box within the wp-admin.

Any ideas?

Comment: 50% is pretty low - please remember to return to your old questions and accept correct answers. It takes them off the 'unanswered' pile and helps others find solutions more easily. People will also be more willing to offer answers if they know that the OP will respond to them. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Give the anchor a class of thickbox and make sure that the thickbox script is enqueued on your admin page using `add_thickbox`

```
add_thickbox();
```

and

```
<a href="your url" class="thickbox">click here</a>
```

You can see what `add_thickbox` does here:

http://hitchhackerguide.com/2011/02/11/add_thickbox/

Comment: I think it might not be necessary to enqueue thickbox: it is automatically (at least in some instances) enqueued on a post edit page. See [`add_thickbox()`](http://hitchhackerguide.com/2011/02/11/add_thickbox/) too.

Comment: So how would I populate it with html?

Comment: Note `your url`, it loads the URL of the anchor into an iframe

Comment: I just spent 40 minutes exporting modal only bootstrap css and JS and getting it into the dashboard -_-. Could have spent 30 seconds doing this...

Answer (score 36):

To use Thickbox for inline modal windows you can use the following code.

```
<?php add_thickbox(); ?>

<a href="#TB_inline?width=600&height=550&inlineId=modal-window-id" class="thickbox">Modal Me</a>

<div id="modal-window-id" style="display:none;">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum sit dolla amet.</p>
</div>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/ThickBox

Comment: Also, It is possible to set a modal window title by adding title attribute to link or button. <a href="**YOUR LINK**" title="**MODAL WINDOW TITLE**" class="**thickbox**">Modal Me</a>